# app not showing data when opend it for the second time

Tags: android

i am looking to make game of questions and answers.i had taken a textview and 4 radio group buttons.and i am fetching data from the external data file from the assets folder.when i installs the app into the emulater it works fine.when i reopens the app in the emulater it is just showing question not showing any text in the radio buttons.here is my code in the data base file

```
public String makeatext(String My_database_table,int i) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = getDatabase();
    String results = new String();

    try {
        String firstColumn = "questions";
    //  final String KEY_ROWID = "id";

        // Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT questions FROM " +
        // My_database_table+ ";",null);
        Cursor c = myDB.query(true, My_database_table,
                new String[] { firstColumn },null, null, null, null, null,
                null);


        int iquestion = c.getColumnIndex(firstColumn);
        if(c.moveToPosition(i)){
        results = c.getString(iquestion)+"\n";
        }

        //while (c.moveToPosition(1)) {
            //String firstName = c.getString(iquestion);
            //results =(" "+ firstName + " ");
        //}
        return results;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR","ERROR in Make test file :"+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return results;
}
```

and in the Activity file i am just calling it as

```
String shoow = myDb.makeatext("question", Qno);
```

showQuestion.setText(shoow);
and on the top of the oncreate methode i initilized the data base as`private final DataBaseHelper myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);`
can any one say me why this is happenig.do i need to write the for loop in the activity file also or shall i take a cursor in the activity class .

plz help me out

thanks in advance

for radio buttons the code in the database file is as follows as i have 4 buttons the code for 4 buttons will be as same as this

```
public String makeExtra1(String My_database_table ,int positions) {
    String results = new String();
    try {
        String secondColumn = "Extra1";
        Cursor c = myDataBase.query(true, My_database_table,
                new String[] { secondColumn }, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        int iExtra1 = c.getColumnIndex(secondColumn);
        if(c.moveToPosition(positions)){
            results = results+c.getString(iExtra1)+"\n";
        }
        return results;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR","ERROR in Make test file :"+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return results;}
```

and in the Activity file

```
    String showextra1 = myDb.makeExtra1("question", Qno);
r0.setText(showextra1);
```

i repeted this thing for 4 times as changing the makeExtra2,3,4 and in the assinged to r1,r2,r3 as above.

Comment: and where do you set text of your radio buttons? please add its code too.

Comment: Can you provide full code of your `Activity` class?

Comment: may be you need to override onResume to setText

Comment: in onResume function what should i write vincent.

Comment: i tried it also .same result .it is showing the question but not showing any thing in the radio buttons .any other hints to do this.plz write u r mail ids i will send code on them.it will be a great help if any one solve it .this game is taking my head off]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should call `Cursor.close()` after reading data from it. Better to do it `finally{}` block.
2. If you want to raise only one answer per query - fill `where` param of `myDataBase.query()`.

Comment: jin35 as i am trying to add c.close(); in to the finally{} block it is giving an error as unrechable code in the eclipse

Comment: oohhh thanks after spending a hole day finally i got the app going correctly as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

The unreachable code error is because you are writing finally{} block after **return results;**

Move this line after the finally{} block, eclipse will not give you any error.

Also do use myDB.close(); in this finally block.